# I want to make \ into a string

Tags: python, string, syntax-error

Edit= Some moderators recommended me to make my self more clear, so here we go.

As a personal project in python, I'm making a very simple software that asks the user for an email address and then checks if the syntaxis of the email is correct.

I made a tuple of special characters that are not allowed in an email address, one of those characters is "\". I was looking online like crazy for how to make \ into a str with no result. I try looking online for the use of the function \ with no result either.

V = "\" doesn't work, it gives me a syntax error. I know it is possible to make it into a string because I've done it with an Input() command.

Please help.

Comment: In what language? You've not provided a tag that indicates that information. Please [edit] your post to add that tag and to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem you're having (a single line of out-of-context code does not provide any information, especially when you've not specified a language).

Comment: Am I clear enough now?(Not passive-agressive)

Comment: It's somewhat clearer (thanks!), but you've still not provided a [mre] (it's still a single line  of code without any context), and *a syntax error* isn't specific enough. That *syntax error* comes with an error message and stack trace, which will provide more information.  Your edit is a start, but it's still not complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what language you're using - but in most cases you need to escape the backslash, as it is an escape character itself.

```
V="\\"
```

This functionality exists that you can include special characters (in this case, a double quote) in the string:

```
V="The following will be in quotes: \"Hello, World\""
```

In this case, the escaped double quotes will be treated as literal characters in the string, and will not signal the end of the string as they would without the escape character.